# How not to push certaines files to certains repos?

Tags: git, heroku, github

I'm working with Heroku, Less(css) and Github.

My source code is hosted on Github[origin] :

- I thus want the less files to be in that repo and
- I don't want the compiled CSS files.

My production environment is the Heroku repository[heroku]:

- I do want the compiled css.
- I do not care about the less files.

Is it possible to define gitignore like filters based upon remote repositories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku will compile your CSS (Rails 3.1 apps) for you if it can't detect you've already compiled it http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar - but also http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile which came out this week.

Even though your Less files will be in your Git repo you *CAN* control what is compiled into your Heroku slug - always good to keep the slug size to a minium - you can use a .slugignore file - http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler

Comment: That is indeed what I need. A .slugignore file. Very interesting. Didn't know it existed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to define gitignore like filters based upon repositories?

Nope.

The only way you could do this is by maintaining two branches, carefully committing and/or cherry-picking between the two branches, and pushing the correct branch to the correct remote. However I don't think this is a workable solution.

When you push to a remote (e.g. heroku, github) you're syncing the git object database and updating what commit SHA the various refs (branches) are pointing at. There's no concept of filtering individual files at this layer, just commits and refs.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Paul